# Improve prformance by editing BitmapFactory.decodeResource method

Tags: android, performance, arraylist, bitmap, bitmapfactory

There are 3 main functions

drawImage :

```
private void drawImage(Canvas canvas) { 
        Bitmap image =
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        getResourceID("img_" + mIndex, "drawable", getApplicationContext()));
        //Draw the image on screen 
         canvas.drawBitmap(image1, mPos.x, mPos.y, null);
    }
```

drawFrame0:

```
    private void drawFrame0() {
        final SurfaceHolder SurfaceHolder = getSurfaceHolder();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

            if (canvas != null) {
               drawImage(canvas);/****draw layer 0*/
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                SurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
```

LiveWThread:

```
 private class LiveWThread extends Thread {
        private  boolean continueRunning;

        Engine engine;

        public MoveBallsThread(Engine e) {
            continueRunning = true ;
            engine = e;
        }
        public void stopRunning() {           
            continueRunning = false ;
        }

        public void run() {

            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            try {
                while (continueRunning) {

                    drawFrame0();
                    //incrementCounter22();
                    mIndex++;
                    ...}
                      }
```

**My question**: is there anyway I can use BitmapFactory.decodeResource to store all my drawables one time only once the app start without using Thread to loop it, because everytime when Thread loads, images have to be decoded all over again and it is obviously slowing down the flow of my images on my live wallpaper..
I will be having ~100 drawables in both jpg and png formats

Many thanks in advance.